# Restricting float precision in c without printf

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I am trying to create code which calculates the minimum number of coins required to give a user the correct change.

The code I have written is almost correct but the number of coins is always off by a little. I'm assuming this is due to the imprecision of numbers with increasing decimal places.

**Is there anyway to limit the float to 2 decimal places?**

For example: 
If I enter 5, it will result in 19 * 25 cents, 2 * 10 cents, 0 * 5cents and 4 * 1 cents.

But the correct amount should be 20 - 0 - 0 - 0 respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

//Assume that the only coins available are quarters (25¢), dimes (10¢), nickels (5¢), and pennies (1¢)

int main(){

float change;
float newTotal;
int coin25 = 0;
int coin10 = 0;
int coin5 = 0;
int coin1 = 0;

    do{
        change = get_float("How much change is owed: $ ");
    }
    while (change <= 0);

   for (float i = 0.25; i < change; i += 0.25){

       coin25 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = change - (coin25 * 0.25);

   for (float j = 0.1; j < newTotal; j += 0.1){

       coin10 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = newTotal - (coin10 * 0.1);

   for (float k = 0.05; k < newTotal; k += 0.05){

       coin5 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = newTotal - (coin5 * 0.05);

   for (float l = 0.01; l < newTotal; l += 0.01){

       coin1 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = newTotal - (coin1 * 0.01);

   //int coins = coin25 + coin10 + coin5 + coin1;
   //printf("%i\n", coins);

   printf("%i\n", coin25);
   printf("%i\n", coin10);
   printf("%i\n", coin5);
   printf("%i\n", coin1);
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 I would but my problem sheet requires me to use floats

Comment: Isnt the minimum amount of coins for 5 dollars all quarters?  so 20-0-0-0?  I dont think im understanding the question here

Comment: @Bwebb You are correct, it should be 20-0-0-0. My mistake.

Comment: @KernelPource yeah, the for loop uses < instead of <=, which for floats is dubious, especially when you get .5 which cant be expressed in binary.  If you scale by 100 so you use cents instead of dollars the .0 should be fine for <= iirc

Comment: @Bwebb That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the inexact nature of floating point types.  The value you're currently working with may be slightly more or slightly less than the value you think you have.  If it happens to be on the low side, you'll end up with less coins that you expect.

For example, the value 0.1 may actually be stored as 0.09999999.  So you would end up with a nickel and four pennies instead of one dime.

Multiply the value you're given by 100 then round it to the nearest integer, then work in cents.  Assuming the value is less than 16M cents, that will give you an exact value.

```
   newTotal = round(change * 100);

   for (int i = 25; i < newTotal ; i += 25){

       coin25 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = change - (coin25 * 25);

   for (int j = 10; j < newTotal; j += 10){

       coin10 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = newTotal - (coin10 * 10);

   for (int k = 5; k < newTotal; k += 5){

       coin5 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = newTotal - (coin5 * 5);

   for (int l = 1; l < newTotal; l += 1){

       coin1 += 1;
   }
   newTotal = newTotal - (coin1 * 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it and it worked! I'm assuming this means there is no way to change the degree of accuracy within a float if I'm not using printf?

Comment: @KernelPource `printf` just changes number of decimal point in output but number in memory is same as before. It is a problem with floating point variables.

Comment: @MohammadAliTaqvazadeh Perfect, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply your input into 100 and get rid of floating point problem. (change dollar input to cent)

And after that you can use `%` operator for calculating result.